# Angular 7 use location.back() and browser back btn won't preserve state

Tags: angular

I have some tab and filters in a list page, and when I go to the detail page, and hit the browser back button, the filtered list page loses the filter and pagination state.

Implementation detail

```
List Page
|-> reference filter component (from another module)
|-> reference pagination component  (from another module)
|-> invoke httpClient in onInit event
```

Questions:

1. Is the history being preserve by default?
2. What should I do if I want it preserve previous page state?

Comment: Use angular router's navigate method to navigate while maintaining history.

Comment: **Typo** alert: **preserve** - not "preseve" ....

Comment: @alt255 I'm using navigate method , and  `Location` from angular/common  , but `ngInit` always firing

Answer (score 1):

Only url is saved, when you navigate between components, you can save the filters in the url. The page component will be destroyed anyway, when you navigate to another one, but you can restore it state from the url after back navigation.

If you don't want to save the filters inside the url, you can create a service which will hold the state. You should inject the state service into a *container* component for your master/details components, so the state will be alive while you navigate between master/detils components, but it will be destroyed automatically when you navigate to another component. For example:

```js
// app.module.ts

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ...
    { path: 'list', component: ListContainerComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: ListComponent },
        { path: 'list/:itemId', ListItemComponent }
    ]},
];
```

```js
// list-container.component.ts

@Component({
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    providers: [
        ListSearchStateService
    ]
})
export class ListContainerComponent {}
```

```js
// list.component.ts

@Component({ ... })
export class ListComponent {
    constructor(
        // state service is available here, you can save the filters inside
        readonly searchState: ListSearchStateService
    ){}
}
```

Another approach might be to use an app global state management framework like [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/) [store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store#ngrxstore). But this solution will have huge impact on the app architecture, so it should be an informed decision. Take a look at this nice article: [Angular Service Layers: Redux, RxJs and Ngrx Store - When to Use a Store And Why?](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/) The second solutions is also described in the article, see *Creating Local state that cleans itself up* section.

Comment: there some state just can not be store and restore in url , for example :  scrollbar state ,  but  angular.io  can preserve scrollbar state  as well , normal page (not SPA)  browser will store every state of current page , when u navigate back , browser will just restore every thing,

Comment: @John Usually browser apps don't store such state as scroll position. What about angular.io, I've looked inside [the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/aio), there isn't a `router-outlet` at all. Looks like it uses a custom navigation logic, which preserves the state somehow.

Comment: @John If the problem is stil interested for you, I've added two another solutions to the answer, I hope it will be helpful.